# escaping the query in a SQLite query with bind params

Tags: sqlite, better-sqlite3

I have a simple FTS5 query like source

```js
function getRes(q) {
    const sel = 'SELECT Count(id) AS c FROM t JOIN v ON t.id = v.id WHERE v MATCH ?';
    return db.prepare(sel).get(q);
}
```

The above fails for `getRes('Trematoda (awaiting allocation)')` with the following error

```
SqliteError: fts5: syntax error near "Trematoda"
```

Of course, it works fine for `getRes('Trematoda')` so it is the parens that are causing the problem. Since I can't guarantee what characters will be in my query, how can I ensure this succeeds? From my Perl+Postgres days, I seem to remember that binding automatically did all the escaping properly. Seems that is not the case with JavaScript+SQLite. On further testing, it fails in the SQLite shell as well but it does work fine in TablePlus, a GUI for SQLite.

Comment: Parentheses have a special meaning in strings matched against fts tables; has nothing to do with the actual parameter binding.

Comment: If you want to match that entire phrase, enclose it in double quotes inside the string being bound. See https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#full_text_query_syntax for more.

Comment: thanks. That worked. I did not realize that parens were meaningful in the MATCH queries. If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as accepted, and it might be useful for others as well.